# Verificar se uma string pertence a uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Esse programa só está imprimindo que a letra inserida pelo usuário é uma consoante, mesmo quando é uma vogal. Acho que tem a ver com o `in` e `not in`, mas não tenho certeza.

```
mensagem= list (input ("Digite qualquer letra\n"))
vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

if mensagem in vogais :
    print ("A letra é uma vogal")
if mensagem not in vogais :
    print ("A letra é uma consoante")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É porque você está transformando a letra em uma lista. O [operador `in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) verifica se algo pertence à lista. Como a lista de vogais só tem strings, só faz sentido testar se strings pertencem à ela.

Portanto, para testar se a letra pertence à lista, não transforme-a em lista, faça simplesmente:

```
mensagem = input("Digite qualquer letra\n")
```

Outro detalhe é que você pode simplificar o código usando apenas `if`/`else`:

```
if mensagem in vogais:
    print("A letra é uma vogal")
else:
    print("A letra é uma consoante")
```

Se a mensagem não está na lista de vogais, ele já cai no `else`. Não há motivo para testar novamente se a letra não pertence à lista.

---

Vale lembrar que esse código é bem "ingênuo", pois se eu digitar "@", ou "!", ou "2", por exemplo, (ou até mesmo uma vogal maiúscula) ele diz que é uma consoante.

Para ser mais preciso, o ideal é ter também uma lista de consoantes:

```
# transforma o que foi digitado em letra minúscula 
mensagem = input("Digite qualquer letra\n").lower()

vogais = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consoantes = ['b', 'c', etc...] # coloque todas as consoantes aqui

if mensagem in vogais:
    print("A letra é uma vogal")
elif mensagem in consoantes:
    print("A letra é uma consoante")
else:
    print("O que foi digitado não é uma vogal nem consoante")
```

Por fim, vale lembrar que esse código não considera letras acentuadas (mas bastaria adicioná-las na lista, se for o caso).

Answer (score 5):

`mensagem` recebe uma lista dos caracteres digitados pelo usuário. Por isso, a comparação com `vogais` só funcionará se você comparar usando um index, assim:

```
mensagem = list(input("Digite qualquer letra\n")
if mensagem[0] in vogais:  # Se houver mais de um caractere, ele será ignorado
    # resto do código
```

Ou se você deixar de transformar o resultado em uma lista, assim:

```
mensagem = input("Digite qualquer letra\n")
if mensagem in vogais:
    # resto do código
```

Se você quiser conferir outros caracteres se o usuário digitar mais de um, você pode usar um for:

```
for caractere in mensagem:
    if caractere in vogais:
        # resto do código
```